# Keyword count in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have a database with two tables, 'person' and 'person_keyword'. I wanna print the number of keywords for each person. What I have tried until now is:

`select person.name, keyword from person JOIN person_keyword ON person.name=person_keyword.keyword`

But this only gives:

```
name       keyword
-----      -----
JOHN       A
JOHN       AD
JOHN       V
SAM        DE
SAM        AS
EVA        AZ
EVA        AS
EVA        FQ
EVA        MQ
```

My expected output looks like this:

```
Name       keyword
-----      -----
JOHN       3
SAM        2
EVA        4
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by`:

```
select p.name, count(*) as cnt 
from person p
inner join person_keyword ok on p.name = pk.keyword
group by p.name
```

Note: unless you really want some filtering on `person`, you could very well get that result directly from `person_keyword`:

```
select keyword as name, count(*) as cnt
from person_keyword
group by keyword
```